# Adding custom CSS to construct 2

Tags: css, construct-2

I am new to game development and I am making a simple game using `construct 2`.

The problem is that construct 2 provides `basic html buttons`, but I want to put `background-image` in button. So for that I want to add a `custom css` in my construct 2 `project`.. But I am not finding any option to add css to my project. I have added the css in my Files Directory, But It doesnt work.. Any help regarding to this will be appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer..
here is a `plugin` for `construct 2` by using which we can **import css** to our construct 2 project..

> https://www.scirra.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=78007&start=0

I am sharing my answer so that it can help another users who are having same problem as me..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 'construct 2' generate a `<button>` tag or generate something else. but if its generate button tag.

you can try this css to apply a background image on `<button>` tag.

--Button CSS--

```
button{background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);}
```

---HTML Button Code--

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Working Demo http://jsbin.com/qupaxufo/1/edit

Comment: Brother I am an 2 year experienced web designer and web developer, If this would be too easy as that than I already have done it before... @Kheema

Comment: We are here to help the people. if you want really a working answer then you have to explained further.. like what HTML render code appear?

Comment: `construct 2` is a `codeless` environment. We dont have to code in that .. Just `drag and drop` environment is there.. No any code is visible... If any code is visible there than I must have done something..

Comment: Great! then using Firefox Extension called `Firebug` can you pelase tell what code generated?

Comment: Already Done it... :( , `firebug` and `developer tools` as well..`external css` are getting generated.. but dont know how and from where...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48331/discussion-between-kheema-pandey-and-nishant-solanki)

Comment: can you chat: so we can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you CAN add CSS in Construct 2 itself:

1. For example, create event, select object that you want to style (but be certain that css is applicable on that object, your target is most probably some kind of input element).
2. Then, select `set CSS style`, enter property and enter its value (ofc, you can't use pseudo-classes and some more advanced stuff, but there are workarounds even for that).